# Creating a string using different kind of switch loops and saving it as a .txt file

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, switch-statement, text-files

I have been given an assignment to ask users to input name, ticket type, and fine amount. I have to keep asking the users until they press the letter q. I have started writing some codes but I cannot seem to figure out how to quit the program using the letter "q". And on top of that, if anyone is willing to give an bonus answer, I have to store this program in a .txt. This is what I have so far:

```
      import java.util.Scanner;
      import java.io.*;

      public class BooleanQ {   

              public static void main(String[] args)    {

      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please insert your name: ");
    String name = console.nextLine();       

    System.out.println("Please insert the type of ticket");
    String ticketType = console.nextLine();     

    System.out.println("Please insert the fine amount: ");
    double fine = console.nextDouble();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just write your code inside while loop**

```js
     import java.io.*;

       public class BooleanQ {
public static void main(String[] args)    {
String userchoice= "";
do {
    
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Please insert your name: ");
    String name = console.nextLine();


    System.out.println("Please insert the type of ticket");
    String ticketType = console.nextLine();


    System.out.println("Please insert the fine amount: ");
    double fine = console.nextDouble();
 System.out.println("To Exit Press q ! ");
 userchoice= console.nextLine();
} while (userchoice!="q");

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now, how do i store it in a .txt file?

Comment: Here is the problem statement.

Comment: Option 1: Ask users to input Person Name, Ticket Type and Fine. You will keep asking users until they press q key. Once user types Q, you will store all the details into the .txt file or any other file